# Write to a file in XCode project directory

Tags: ios, file, directory, save

I have a file that I have included in my XCode project that I would like to overwrite. The file is called Introduction.html in a directory called book

In the screen shot you can see where it is in the directory and my various attempts to write to it.

[image]

Any help would be great thanks!

*edit* My code is not that readable in the picture:

```
 //Atempt 1
NSString *myString = [mutableArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/book/Introduction.html"];
[myString writeToFile:path atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

//Attempt 2
[myString writeToFile:@"/book/Introduction.html" atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

//Attempt 3
NSArray *paths2 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths2 objectAtIndex: 0];
NSString *docFile = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"book/Introduction.html"];    
[myString writeToFile: docFile atomically:NO encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];


//Attempt 4
NSFileHandle *file;
NSMutableData *data;
const char *bytestring = "black dog";    
data = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:bytestring 
                             length:strlen(bytestring)];
file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath: 
        @"book/Introduction.html"];
if (file == nil)
    NSLog(@"Failed to open file");
[file seekToFileOffset: 10];
[file writeData: data];
[file closeFile];
[file release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

itgiawa,

as far as I've read the docs, files "in my XCode project" cannot be overwritten, because the sandboxing mechanism in iOS doesn't allow your app to access this space. I remember reading the directive "if you need to overwrite data which shipped with your app, copy them to the Documents directory and overwrite the copy."

So I'd say your attempt 1 comes closest, save the fact that you need to copy the file from your resources bundle into the Documents directory first.

Regards, nobi